# Few conditional counts in a single query work unexpectedly

Tags: sqlite, count, subquery

```
SELECT HR.name, (SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE Ord.status > 6), (SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE Ord.status < 6)
        FROM Ord
            JOIN Manager AS Mng ON Mng.person_id = Ord.manager_id
            JOIN Person AS HR ON HR.id = Mng.hr_id 
        GROUP BY HR.id
```

HR has managers that he has found.

```
"CREATE TABLE Manager (person_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, hr_id INTEGER)"
```

I want to count for every HR how many Orders made by his managers has `status > 6` and witch doesn't.

Query I've written upper doesn't return proper result. (But return some).

Answer (score 0):

Your description is incomprehensible.

Your query lacks `FROM` clauses and correlations in the subqueries, and the opposite of `>` would be `<=`.
You probably want something like this:

```
SELECT HR.name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Ord
        WHERE Ord.manager_id IN (SELECT Mng.person_id
                                 FROM Manager as Mng
                                 WHERE Mng.hr_id = HR.id)
          AND Ord.status > 6),
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Ord
        WHERE Ord.manager_id IN (SELECT Mng.person_id
                                 FROM Manager as Mng
                                 WHERE Mng.hr_id = HR.id)
          AND Ord.status <= 6),
FROM Person AS HR
GROUP BY HR.id
```